Optimize integer division when divisor is >sqrt(dividend)?
Is it possible to speed up multi-byte unsigned integer division when the divisor is:

Known to be greater than the square root of the dividend
A run-time value. I.e. not a compile time constant

E.g.
uint32_t b = (uint32_t)UINT16_MAX*2U; // Arbitrary runtime divisor  **greater than UINT16_MAX**
uint32_t a = b * 123U;                // Arbitrary runtime dividend **greater than b**

// Is there some magic combination of addition, subtraction, multiply or 
// bit twiddling that could be used instead of 32-bit division given the constraints?
uint32_t result = a/b; 

This is for an 8-bit embedded system with no hardware divider. It does support multi-byte (16-, 32-, 64-) division in software - but it's slow.
Q&A Edit
I was hoping to keep this as a generic question, but here are the specifics:

Target CPU architecture is AVR.

No hardware division
No clzinstruction
The software division routines appear to loop based on
operand size not quotient size. E.g. __udivmodsi4
The instruction set

Has a small number of 16 bit instructions:

ADIW – Add Immediate to Word
MOVW – Copy Register Word
SBIW – Subtract Immediate from Word


Has built in multiply instructions




Compiler is AVR-GCC 7.3, compilation with -03. It is an older compiler but it is the current Arduino standard.
I'm aware of libdivide, it's not applicable here.


Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one tag and delete the other. Even if you would like an answer in either language, future users of Stack Overflow may be searching for an answer in one particular language, and search results that do not provide it may disappoint and frustrate users. A question may be asked for separate languages in separate questions.

This sounds like more of an assembly language, or compiler, question.

Please [edit] your question and add details about the compiler you use. Please specify the requirements for the precision in your application. Maybe you can use bit-shifting to reduce the number of bytes for the division, e.g. 2 bytes instead of 4. Did you check the optimization settings of the compiler and the resulting code? With modern compilers you can assume that the compiler will do a good job in optimizing your code.

Well, you can know from this constraint that result can fit in 16 bits only. Also you can know that it is less than b. So you can do a binary search for the result between 0 and min(b, 65535) which is 16 iterations (maybe off by 1 here) with multiplications (and comparisons) maximum. But I doubt it will be faster than the built-in division.

The existing software division probably has a loop whose number of iterations depends on the size of the quotient?

C and C++ are distinct languages.  I don't recommend mixing them (that's why you tagged both, right?).  The C++ language has function and operator overloading which makes linking it with C language difficult.  There's also exceptions and inheritance which the C language doesn't have.  I recommend picking one language, and adjusting your language tags.

Division takes a lot of time, either by hand or by processor.  Can you eliminate the divisions by using a different algorithm?

If the same divisor will be used multiple times (e.g. in a loop) you could make use of libdivide. It has some overhead to set up division by a particular number, so whether or not it is a win will depend on how many divisions are to be done with the divisor.

Is the multiplication slow too? Only having an 8-bit register will be a bit like the longhand method. A binary search was suggested with possibly 16 iterations, each requiring a multiplication. But the traditional shift-compare-subtract division method will also need max 16 iterations too (if you first align the operands). Multi-byte comparison and subtraction is much quicker than multi-byte multiplication.

Does this 8-bit processor support only pure 8-bit operations, or can it also perform a limited number of 16-bit operations by pairing up registers (e.g. in the manner of the Z80)? Does it have a hardware multiplier? If so, is there a convenient way of producing the double-width product, e.g. 8x8->16 bit multiply? Does the CPU support a count leading zeros (CLZ) operation? Does it support conditional move, or select-type instructions?

On https://godbolt.org/z/v8n81dY44, with optimization, libgcc function __udivmodsi4 is called: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/udivmodsi4.c Is this the slow code you see? Or the code from a compilation without optimization?

@Bodo This will be calling the AVR runtime library that implements that intrinsic, not the libgcc version - I linked to the source in the question.
However, the source you linked to has been useful. Thank you!

if a is 123 times b:
uint32_t a = b * 123U;

then a/b= 123U*a/a= 123U (if you don't care about wrap-around overflow. But I guess you mean arbitrary a and b.
Clang has __builtin_assume, maybe it will help.
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t special_div(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    __builtin_assume(b > UINT16_MAX);
    return a / b;
}

Or you could try other optimizer hints with unreachable and so on.
Otherwise you should look at your software divison implementation and optimise it based on your assumptions.
If your 16-bit divide is faster than the 32 bit divide, I could think of simplifying it this way:
a / b = (n * (1 << 16))/(m * (1 << 16)) = n / m
where n = a >> 16 and m = b >> 16

The as n / m is only a 16-bit division it might be faster.
EDIT:
Consider the classic schoolbook algorithm for division:
uint32_t div(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    if (b == 0) { return DIV_BY_ZERO; }
    uint32_t quotient = 0;
    uint32_t remainder = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 32 - 1; i < 32; i--) {
        remainder = remainder << 1;
        remainder |= (a >> i) & 1;
        if (remainder >= b) {
            remainder = remainder - b;
            quotient = quotient | (1 << i);
        }
    }
    return quotient;
}

You know that the denominator b is always greater than the remainder for the first 16 iterations of the loop. So you can rewrite the division as.
uint32_t fastdiv(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    if (b == 0) { return DIV_BY_ZERO; }
    uint32_t quotient = 0;
    uint32_t remainder = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 32 - 1; i > 16; i--) {
        remainder = remainder << 1;
        remainder |= (a >> i) & 1;
        // essentially a 16 bit bitreverse
    }
    for (uint32_t i = 16; i < 32; i--) {
        remainder = remainder << 1;
        remainder |= (a >> i) & 1;
        if (remainder >= b) {
            remainder = remainder - b;
            quotient = quotient | (1 << i);
        }
    }
    return quotient;
}

So if you have an efficient way to reverse 16 bits it might work. Or you could waste a lot of memory with a lookup table.
After thinking more about this, I came to the conclusion that I cannot really help you.

Using shifts and a 16-bit divide loses accuracy. E.g. 32292987/262141 = 123 => (rshift 16) 492/3 = 164. I tried applying rounding to the shifts (since they are equivalent to division by 65536) & it improves the results somewhat, but there are still inaccuracies.

Oh, I misunderstood since you used a mutliple in the example. I should have looked at the comment, you mean just greater.

Well I have thought about this a bit and only came up with the thing in the EDIT section (I doubt it will be faster).   This problem may need someone with more experience than I have.
